How can I define an enum type in OPC-UA server?
I use the NuGet library OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua.Server and cannot find any simple examples about how to create custom types like enumerations.

Derive from CustomNodeManager2 (I named it DataAccessNodeManager) and add the following method to it:
private NodeId AddDataType<T>() where T : struct, Enum
{
    var enumFields = Enum
        .GetNames<T>()
        .Zip(Enum.GetValues<T>())
        .Select(item =>
        {
            return new EnumField
            {
                Name = item.First,
                Value = Convert.ToInt32(item.Second)
            };
        })
        .ToArray();

    var enumDefinition = new EnumDefinition { Fields = enumFields };
    var nodeId = new NodeId(++_nodeId, NamespaceIndex);

    var enumType = new DataTypeState()
    {
        NodeId = nodeId,
        BrowseName = typeof(T).Name,
        DisplayName = typeof(T).Name,
        SuperTypeId = DataTypeIds.Enumeration,
        DataTypeDefinition = new ExtensionObject(enumDefinition)
    };
    
    AddPredefinedNode(SystemContext, enumType);

    return nodeId;
}

Then, in your derived class, use it as follows:
class DataAccessNodeManager : CustomNodeManager2
{
    public DataAccessNodeManager(IServerInternal server)
        : base(server, ...)
    {
        //
    }

    public override void CreateAddressSpace(IDictionary<NodeId, IList<IReference>> externalReferences)
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            var myNodeId = AddDataType<HlbCompressor>();

            // ... add other nodes and use myNodeId for the `DataType` property 
        } 
    }
}

The often used UaExpert client software then shows the enum name next to its value:

